# Convert a nested Array to Scalar and then reconvert the scalar to nested array

Tags: php

I have an array that looks like this.

```php
$array = [
    0 => 'abc',
    1 => [
        0 => 'def',
        1 => 'ghi'
    ],
    'assoc1' => [
        'nassoc' => 'jkl',
        'nassoc2' => 'mno',
        'nassoc3' => '',
        'nassoc4' => false
    ]
];
```

The `$array` can have numeric keys or be an assoc array or a mixed one. The level of nesting is not known. Also the values of the array can also be `bool` or `null` or an empty string `''`

I need to able to convert this into a scalar array with key value pairs. And then later reconvert it back to the exact same array.

So the scalar array could look like

```php
$arrayScalar = [
    '0' => 'abc',
    '1[0]' => 'def',
    '1[1]' => 'ghi',
    'assoc1[nassoc]' => 'jkl',
    'assoc1[nassoc2]' => 'mno',
    'assoc1[nassoc3]' => '',
    'assoc1[nassoc4]' => false
];
```

And then later be able to get back to the initial `$array`.

I wrote a parser and it does not currently handle bool values correctly.
I have a feeling this is at best a super hacky method to do what I am after. Also I have been able to test it only so much.

```php
function flattenNestedArraysRecursively($nestedArray, $parent = '', &$flattened = [])
    {
        $keys = array_keys($nestedArray);
        if (empty($keys)) {
            $flattened[$parent] = 'emptyarray';
        } else {
            foreach ($keys as $value) {
                if (is_array($nestedArray[$value])) {
                    $reqParent = (!empty($parent)) ? $parent . '|!|' . $value : $value;
                    $this->flattenNestedArraysRecursively($nestedArray[$value], $reqParent, $flattened);
                } else {
                    $reqKey = (!empty($parent)) ? $parent . '|!|' . $value : $value;
                    $flattened[$reqKey] = $nestedArray[$value];
                }
            }
        }
        return $flattened;
    }

function reCreateFlattenedArray($flatArray): array
    {
        $arr = [];
        foreach ($flatArray as $key => $value) {
            $keys = explode('|!|', $key);
            $arr = $this->reCreateArrayRecursiveWorker($keys, $value, $arr);
        }
        return $arr;
    }

    function reCreateArrayRecursiveWorker($keys, $value, $existingArr)
    {
        //Outside to Inside
        $keyCur = array_shift($keys);

        //Check if keyCur Exists in the existingArray
        if (key_exists($keyCur, $existingArr)) {
            // Check if we have reached the deepest level
            if (empty($keys)) {
                //Return the Key => value mapping
                $existingArr[$keyCur] = $value;
                return $existingArr;
            } else {
                // If not then continue to go deeper while appending deeper levels values to current key
                $existingArr[$keyCur] = $this->reCreateArrayRecursiveWorker($keys, $value, $existingArr[$keyCur]);
                return $existingArr;
            }
        } else {
            // If Key does not exists in current Array
            // Check deepest
            if (empty($keys)) {
                //Return the Key => value mapping
                $existingArr[$keyCur] = $value;
                return $existingArr;
            } else {
                // Add the key
                $existingArr[$keyCur] = $this->reCreateArrayRecursiveWorker($keys, $value, []);
                return $existingArr;
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there a better more elegant way of doing this, maybe `http_build_query` or something else I am not aware of.

Sandbox link -> http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/50b3890e5bdc515bc145eda0a1b34c29eefadcca

Comment: What is the ultimate purpose of doing this? Is it just an exercise, or are you trying to accomplish something else?

Comment: @kmoser Well, it is a part of a complicated system where we have to build an array that is used by a third party api (hence the structure cannot be controlled). We have to do this for many many apis (hence we cannot hard code it). Also the values `abc`, `def` is actually a variable that is filled with data from the database, which is submitted by the user. Hence we cannot predict the exact values too. In the end the array is json_encoded and sent to the api.

Comment: @kmoser I mean we actually create a key value association (via a web form used by admins) for each field in the array and that is where the scalar array would be used. And when sending it to the api we parse it back to the array.

Comment: `'0[0]' => 'def'` should be `1[0] => 'def'` I presume

Comment: @nice_dev yes that is correct. I edited the question to show the correct notation.

Comment: @endeavour Great, so if I put an answer for flattening, will you `reCreateFlattenedArray` the result yourself ?

Comment: @nice_dev I will try and I presume I would be able to do that but if I get stuck, will post here. :)

Comment: @endeavour Sure. But never mind, I will try the `reCreateFlattenedArray` too since it is already a part of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Flattening:**

Your approach towards recursion is correct. I think we can make it more simpler.

- We loop over the array. if the value is *an array in itself*, we recursively make a call to this new child subarray.
- This way, we visit each key and each value. Now, we are only left to manage the keys to assign them when adding to our final resultant array, say `$arrayScalar`.
- For this, we make a new function parameter which takes the parent key into account when assigning. That's it.

**Snippet:**

```
$arrayScalar = [];
function flatten($array,&$arrayScalar,$parent_key){
    foreach($array as $key => $value){
        $curr_key = empty($parent_key) ? $key : $parent_key . '[' . $key . ']';
        if(is_array($value)){
            flatten($value,$arrayScalar,$curr_key);
        }else{
            $arrayScalar[$curr_key] = $value;
        }
    }
}

flatten($array,$arrayScalar,'');
var_export($arrayScalar);
```

**Demo:** http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1e3092e9e163330f43d495cc9d4acb672289a987

---

**Unflattening:**

- This one is a little tricky.
- You might have already noticed that the keys in the flattened array are of the form `key1[key2][key3][key4]` etc.
- So, we collect all these individually in a new array, say `$split_key`. It might look like this.

  array (
  'key1',
  'key2',
  'key3',
  'key4',
  )
- To achieve the above, we do a basic string parsing and added in-between keys to the array whenever we reach the end of the key string or `[` or `]`.
- Next, to add them to our final resultant array, we loop over the collected keys and check if they are set in our final array. If not so, set them. We now pass child array reference to our temporary variable `$temp`. This is to edit the same copy of the array. In the end, we return the result.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

function unflatten($arrayScalar){
    $result = [];
    foreach($arrayScalar as $key => $value){
        if(is_int($key)) $key = strval($key);
        $split_key = [];
        $key_len = strlen($key);
        $curr = '';
        // collect them as individual keys
        for($i = 0; $i < $key_len; ++$i){
            if($key[ $i ] == '[' || $key[ $i ] == ']'){
                if(strlen($curr) === 0) continue;
                $split_key[] = $curr;
                $curr = '';
            }else{
                $curr .= $key[ $i ];
            }
            
            if($i === $key_len - 1 && strlen($curr) > 0){
                $split_key[] = $curr;
            }
        }
        // collecting them ends
        
        //add them to our resultant array.
        $temp = &$result;
        foreach($split_key as $sk){
            if(!isset($temp[ $sk ])){
                $temp[ $sk ] = [];
            }
            $temp = &$temp[$sk];
        }        
        $temp = $value;
    }
    return $result;
}

var_export(unflatten($arrayScalar));
```

**Demo:** http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/66136a699c3c5285eed3d3350ed4faa5bbce4b76